# Water solubility of different types of Iron III

Tags: aqueous-solution, solubility, iron

For an experiment I require an aqueous solution of Iron(III). My school has the following compounds, which of them are water soluble? I believe that only Iron(III) oxide is **insoluble**, but I would like to verify.

- Iron(III) oxide
- Iron(III) oxalate
- Iron(III) chloride-hexahydrate

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you thoroughly consulted the topic with textbooks, Wikipedia and Google ?

Comment: Yes, according to Google, Iron(III) Oxide is insoluble, Iron(III) Oxalate and Iron(III) Chloride-Hexahydrate are soluble. Is this correct?

Comment: [Ferric oxalate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferric_oxalate) is reportedly rather just slighly soluble, so for practical means, consider it insoluble. [Ferric chloride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron(III)_chloride) hexahydrate is well soluble, routinely used in dissolving copper from printed circuit boards.
You can find this quite easily.

Comment: Next time, more thorough searching.

Comment: Anyway the choice of Iron(III) oxalate is not happy, because it is a substance that can only be synthesized in the darkness. It is destroyed by the visible light, according to the equation $$\ce{Fe2(C2O4)3 + light ->  2 FeC2O4 + 2 CO2}$$ This reaction  is even the basis of the photochemical process called heliography.

Comment: Something similar happens for ammonium ferric citrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Iron(III) oxide is insoluble.
- Iron(III) oxalate is, in practical situations, insoluble.
- Iron(III) chloride-hexahydrate is soluble.

Aditionally, Iron(III) oxalate is destroyed by visible light, and I intend to complete my experiment during the day, especially considering that involves colour changes.